# How to connect to a .Net WCF MS-LWSSP SOAP service from Java (JRuby)?

Tags: java, .net, wcf, soap, wsdl

I'm working with a client that's on a currently purely-MRI Ruby/Rails stack, but we have a 3'rd party service we need to start interfacing with that is built on .Net with WCF and the only way to access it is SOAP. They are using MS-LWSSP ([MS documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd357239%28prot.20%29.aspx)) as a security protocol and none of the Ruby SOAP libraries seem to understand how to connect to it.

We are considering adding JRuby to the tech stack (as a separate small application) to connect to this service, as Java has offers more choices for dealing with SOAP. However, I'm not familiar with any of the Java SOAP libraries.

I have seen some other posts about using a Java client to connect to a .Net SOAP service, but I have not seen any specifically addressing using this security protocol. Their SOAP service is SOAP version 1.2 and it does have a WSDL we can access.

Has anyone done this? Could you please provide me with information about what libraries would be helpful in doing so?

Thank you very much for any suggestions or information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an old question now, but I'll respond with what worked for us. Or more correctly, what never worked for us.

None of the Ruby SOAP libraries were compatible with the protocol we had to use. We spent quite a bit of time on trying them out but they simply didn't work with the client. We considered look into implementing the protocol ourselves, but that was far more effort than we wanted to spend on this.

In the end, we requested the client to give us access via a non-SOAP route and that worked out much better.

The moral of the story: try asking if you can have non-SOAP access. It'll save you a lot of effort and headaches.